# equals for arrayList is not being called, ever

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

I have Client class, which contains ArrayList of Category objects. So, when I want to make sure that some sort of Category object exists (by that I mean Categories name is the same), I call .contains() method for array list of categories.

I overrriden .equals() method in Category class like so:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    boolean isEqual = false;
    Log.d("Category", "IT WORKS");
    if (object != null && object instanceof Category) {
        isEqual = (this.name == ((Category) object).getName());
    }

    return isEqual;
}
```

But in the console I am able to see, that equals method is never being called.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Is `name` a string? If so you should be using `equals` instead of `==`. Also, you don't need to check for `null` since `null instanceof SomeClass` will return false anyway. These things won't solve your problem, but they're worth looking at.

Comment: try debugging it will certainly invoke, + there is a bug in your `equals()`, here `isEqual = (this.name == ((Category) object).getName());` I assume `name` is of `String` and you used `==` instead of `equals()`

Comment: Did you also override getHashCode()? You have to do it all the time you override equals().

Comment: @Matt why *`hashcode()`* for `ArrayList` ?

Comment: @Jigar Sort of a reflex, I guess. I suppose you are right - ArrayList isn't likely to make use of hashCode(). I see it as a general advice - without having hashCode() it's likely that problems with equals() will arise sooner or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29):

> `boolean contains(Object o)`
>    Returns `true` if this list contains the
>   specified element.
>   More formally, returns `true` if and only if this
>   list contains at least one element `e` such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.
>   Specified by: `contains` in interface `Collection<E>`

So, when you call `list.contains(o)`, the `equals` is called on `o` and not on the element of the list.

Something like

```
boolean contains(o)
{
    for every e in list loop
        if o.equals(e)
            return true
    end loop
    return false
}
```

Depending on how you are calling `contains` and the parameter to it, the equals being called may be in a completely different class (of the object in the parameter).

Answer (score 2):

I tested it like so,

```
static class Category {
    public Category(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o != null && o instanceof Category) {
            return this.getName().equals(((Category) o).getName());
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Category> al = new ArrayList<>();
    al.add(new Category("test"));
    System.out.println(al.contains(new Category("test")));
}
```

Output is

```
true
```

Comment: Perfect. It was simple and short